# Insertion Sort with Objects, Strings and Arraylists

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, insertion-sort

I am having trouble with my Insertion Sort code.

public static ArrayList  InsertionSort (ArrayList playersNames){

```
    System.out.println("roster will now be sorted");

    for (int i = 1; i < playersNames.size();i++){

        int j = i - 1;
         Baller tempx = playersNames.get(i);
         Baller tempy = playersNames.get(j);
         while (j >= 0 &&  tempx.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(tempy.getName())< 0){
            playersNames.set(i, tempy);
            playersNames.set(j+1, tempx);
            j--;

         }


        System.out.println(playersNames);
    }

    return playersNames;
}
```

The output isn't being outputted properly.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few minor changes I think you need to make to the code that should address the issues you're having.

Let's look at this part of the code:

```
     int j = i - 1;
     Baller tempx = playersNames.get(i);
     Baller tempy = playersNames.get(j);
     while (j >= 0 &&  tempx.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(tempy.getName())< 0){
        playersNames.set(i, tempy);
        playersNames.set(j+1, tempx);
        j--;

     }
```

The idea here is to repeatedly swap the current element with the previous element until it ends up in the right place. That's the right idea, but there's a small bug: after you make the swap, `tempy` still refers to the element that was at position `playersNames.get(i - 1)`, so the next iteration of the loop will compare the wrong two elements. Additionally, you're always performing swaps at position `i` (where the current element started), but you should be swapping at position `j+1` (where the current element is at the moment).

To change this, you have a few options. I think the cleanest option would be to eliminate the `tempx` and `tempy` variables to ensure that you can't accidentally make this mistake and just access things by index instead. For example:

```
     int j = i - 1;
     while (j >= 0 &&
            playersNames.get(j).getName().compareToIgnoreCase(playersNames.get(j+1).getName().getName()) < 0){
        Baller temp = playersNames.get(j);
        playersNames.set(j, playersNames.get(j+1));
        playersNames.set(j+1, temp);
        j--;
     }
```